# Microsoft Sql Server management studio not recognizing unicode Kannada Font

Tags: sql-server, unicode, fonts

I have Microsoft Sql server management studio 2014 and i need to store statments in Kannada in it.
I have unicode kannada font BRH Kannada installed in my laptop , and visual studio is successfully displaying kannada.
I created my table and give my column nvarchar as the data type.

When i am inserting data, the kannada statements are being displayed as they are but when i retrieve using Select statement, it's showing ?? for each character.
I set the font of grid result as Arial Unicode MS also, still it's showing ??.

Comment: Kindly show your query you used to retrive the data

Comment: Did you add **N** like `Select N'column_name' from Table_name`in your query

Comment: @rajesh select * from mytable

Answer (score 2):

I understood my mistake..
https://aalamrangi.wordpress.com/2012/05/13/storing-and-retrieving-non-english-unicode-characters-hindi-czech-arabic-etc-in-sql-server/

Data is supposed to be inserted with an N before it..N''